# Youtube API 3 video thumbnails

Tags: python-3.x, youtube-api

Is it possible to generate and extract custom number of thumbnails for a YouTube video with YouTube API3? I know YouTube generates 4 random thumbnails, but I was wondering if there is a way to set a custom number of those. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I tried looking it up and I did not find any documentations that contain information about this feature. It is most likely not supported as of the moment.

Comment: thats what I thought! thanks!